# CPU architecture scanning using bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am working on a toolkit for the company i work for, the problem is, one of the tools in this 'kit' needs to have the ability to recognize architectures, i already got 32 and 64 bits working but i cant get arm to work, can anyone help? this is what i got and need..

```
if [ "$arch" == 'armv' ];
then
echo "ARM Architecture
```

What i want it to do is that when a arm architecture (6 or 7 i dont really care about that point) is detected, that it just says arm architecture, but i already tried editing

```
if [ "$arch" == 'armv' ];
```

to

```
if [ "$arch" == 'armv*' ];
```

If someone knows a solution any help would be welcome.

Oh and i use shell/bash because they dont want any additional programs on the machines, so i use bash and shell scripting so they have their own programs :)

**------------------** **EDIT** **------------------**

Here is the code fully so you guys can have a idea of what im trying

```
arch=$(uname -i)

if [ "$arch" == 'x86_64' ];
then 
echo "X64 Architecture" 
fi

if [ "$arch" == 'x86_32' ];
then
echo "X32 Architecture"
fi

if [ "$arch" == 'armv*' ];
then
echo "Arm architecture"
fi
```

Comment: Does the "uname -i" output meet your needs?

Comment: yes it does but it isnt what i need, i saw that i didnt add in what i ment, here

`arch=$(uname -i)

if [ "$arch" == 'x86_64' ];
then
echo "X64 Architecture"
fi`

for example, it works with both 32 and 64 bits but i cant get it to work with arm, i want/need to make it so that if the arch from `uname -i` = armv** that it automaticly see's it as a arm cpu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pattern would work if you would use the `bash` keyword, `[[`, instead of the `[` (`test`) builtin and remove the quotes from the glob pattern:

```
[[ $arch == arm* ]] && echo 'This is ARM Architecture'
```

You can also use the Regular expression matching using the `[[` keyword and `=~` operator:

```
[[ $arch =~ ^arm ]] && echo 'This is ARM Architecture'
```

`^arm` checks whether the variable `$arch` contains `arm` at the start (Regex token `^` matches the start of a line).

---

Also, for 32 bit architectures, `uname -i` should show `i386` or `i686` or `i486`, not `x86_32`.

On a different note, you should use `elif` construct rather that using `if` three times, it was designed for tasks like this. So your full script can be rewritten as:

```bsh
arch=$(uname -i)
if [[ $arch == x86_64* ]]; then
    echo "X64 Architecture"
elif [[ $arch == i*86 ]]; then
    echo "X32 Architecture"
elif  [[ $arch == arm* ]]; then
    echo "ARM Architecture"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use Bash-isms like `[[ ... ]]` you can also use `case` blocks to glob-match strings and branch according to the match result:

```
arch=`uname -i`
case "$arch" in
  x86_64|amd64)
    echo X64;;
  i?86)
    echo X32;;
  arm*)
    echo ARM;;
  powerpc|ppc64)
    echo PowerPC;;
  *)
    printf 'Unsupported architecture: "%s"\n' "$arch" >&2; exit 2;;
esac
```

`case` blocks may also be more readable than a series of `if ... then ... elif` blocks if there are more than 2 or 3 branches.

Answer (score 2):

On Jetson Nano you will see: aarch64

AArch64 is the 64-bit state introduced in the Armv8-A architecture
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#ARMv8-A

```
arch=$(uname -i)
if [[ $arch == x86_64* ]]; then
    echo "X64 Architecture"
elif [[ $arch == i*86 ]]; then
    echo "X32 Architecture"
elif  [[ $arch == arm* ]] || [[ $arch = aarch64 ]]; then
    echo "ARM Architecture"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

On some distros, for example Arch and Manjaro, the `-i` might return `unknown`.

So `uname --machine` is what should be used for greater compatibility. It will output `x86_64` and this works universally on all distros I have checked **including** Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

While Mehrad Mahmoudian's answer above does work, the much simpler -m flag performs the exact same function and has support in other OS.

If you're looking for compatibility, I highly suggest you use something like this instead:

```
ARCH=$(uname -m)
if [[ "$ARCH" == x86_64* ]]; then
  echo "X64 Architecture"
elif [[ "$ARCH" == i*86 ]]; then
  echo "X32 Architecture"
elif  [[ "$ARCH" == arm* ]]; then
  echo "ARM Architecture"
fi
```

The reason being is that,

```
uname -m
```

will work in both Ubuntu and OSX, while

```
uname --machine
```

only works in Ubuntu, and returns an illegal option in OSX.